# Merging two-dimensional arrays into groups

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am refactoring a calendar app. The calendar has a user-defined grid (slots where bookings can occur), but needs to display "off-the-grid" bookings as well. Think of "regular" slots at 08:00, 09:00 and "irregular" slots when someone is booked at 08:39. For business reasons, I need to display these slots differently (CSS), otherwise they behave the same. I've searched the PHP Manual, but the built-in array functions don't do exactly what I need.

```
$officialGrid = array(
    array('grid' => TRUE, 'time' => '08:00', 'content' => NULL),
    array('grid' => TRUE, 'time' => '09:00', 'content' => NULL));

$bookings = array(
    array('grid' => NULL, 'time' => '08:00', 'content' => 'Paul Simon'),
    array('grid' => NULL, 'time' => '08:00', 'content' => 'Art Garfunkel'),
    array('grid' => NULL, 'time' => '08:39', 'content' => 'Homer J. Simpson'));
```

I could just append these arrays, but for performance reasons would like shorten the result to:

```
$timeSlotsToDisplay = array(
    array('grid' => TRUE, 'time' => '08:00', 'content' => 'Paul Simon, Art Garfunkel'), //regular
    array('grid' => NULL, 'time' => '08:39', 'content' => 'Homer J. Simpson'), //irregular
    array('grid' => TRUE, 'time' => '09:00', 'content' => NULL)); //vacant
```

I'm also flexible to change data types for the values (`content` might be an array). Is there any elegant solution for merging these arrays, other than start looping and comparing?

PS: Just to illustrate, in PostgreSQL terms, I need to `SELECT DISTINCT ON (time) grid, time, string_agg(content) FROM myDB GROUP BY time ORDER BY time, grid;` (please ignore possible keywords, not quoting due to formatting, also haven't tested the query).

Comment: Not that i know of. loops are not evil though...

Comment: It is better to have time as keys (for the officialGrid)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see nothing wrong with the loops.. but I suggest another structure for the `$officialGrid` array

```
$officialGrid = array(
    '08:00' => array('grid' => TRUE, 'content' => NULL),
    '09:00' => array('grid' => TRUE, 'content' => NULL));

$bookings = array(
    array('grid' => NULL, 'time' => '08:00', 'content' => 'Paul Simon'),
    array('grid' => NULL, 'time' => '08:00', 'content' => 'Art Garfunkel'),
    array('grid' => NULL, 'time' => '08:39', 'content' => 'Homer J. Simpson'));

$timeSlotsToDisplay = $officialGrid;

array_map(function($el) use(&$timeSlotsToDisplay, $officialGrid) {
   $timeSlotsToDisplay[$el['time']] = array(
     'content' => 
       (isset($timeSlotsToDisplay[$el['time']]) ?
        trim($timeSlotsToDisplay[$el['time']]['content'], ',') . ',' : '') .
       $el['content'],
     'grid' => isset($officialGrid[$el['time']]) ? true : null
   );
}, $bookings);

ksort($timeSlotsToDisplay);
var_dump($timeSlotsToDisplay);
```

`array_map` can be replaced by a single `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 0):

> "I've searched the PHP Manual, but the built-in array functions don't
>   do exactly what I need."

Built in arrays features are more effective than just looping through a bunch of arrays, you should take a look at [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) and [array_merge_recursive](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php) in php for a more efficient answer of how to do this, or doing it as the information is pulled down from the database with SQL.

As for a practical php solution possibly if you could loop through every row in each 2d arrays and take the information you want, however this assumes that the keys of each array in $officialGrid is structured the same as  keys of each array in $bookings. It should loop and match data where its the same based on 'time', and skip the ones in booking which don't match. Depending on how many rows of information you have  loops are fine to use with arrays, but they are far from optimal.

```
    $officialGrid = Array(
        Array('grid' => TRUE, 'time' => '08:00'  // ... arrays assumed to be populated with example data above

    $bookings = Array(
        Array('grid' => NULL, 'time' => '08:00'  // ... arrays assumed to be populated with example data above

    // fill final array with content from $bookings
    $timeSlotsToDisplay = $bookings;


    foreach($officialGrid as $officalkey=>$officalobj) {
        foreach($timeSlotsToDisplay as $bookkey=>$obj) {
            if(!isset($officialGrid[$officalobj['time']]) || !isset($timeSlotsToDisplay[$bookobj['time']])) {
               //one of them is not set.. error
            }

                //if the times match when looping
            if( $officialGrid[$officalobj['time']] == $timeSlotsToDisplay[$bookobj['time']]) {
                //keeps the information from officialgrid  data for column, and keep $booking data for content column
            //the null grid entries will just stay the same, as $bookings oringally had
                $timeSlotsToDisplay[$officalobj['grid']];
                $timeSlotsToDisplay[$bookobj['time']] 
                $timeSlotsToDisplay[$bookobj['content']];
            }
        }
    }
```